# Difficulty in finding the peak in the data

Tags: plotting

I have a set of $ x $ and $ y $ data. The $ y $ data is represented in a logarithm scale and the $ x $ data is in linear scale. I have used `FindPeaks` function to find the peaks, but I am not getting results.

```
x = Range[1,200,1];
y = {8.02427*10^-7,8.14262*10^-7,8.34793*10^-7,8.65369*10^-7,9.08187*10^-7,9.66738*10^-7,1.04662*10^-6,1.15719*10^-6,1.31501*10^-6,1.55225*10^-6,1.94033*10^-6,2.67535*10^-6,4.55978*10^-6,0.0000193023,7.75876*10^-6,3.09643*10^-6,1.88471*10^-6,1.32978*10^-6,1.01272*10^-6,8.08314*10^-7,6.66049*10^-7,5.61645*10^-7,4.81987*10^-7,4.1937*10^-7,3.68975*10^-7,3.27632*10^-7,2.93172*10^-7,2.64062*10^-7,2.39189*10^-7,2.17724*10^-7,1.99039*10^-7,1.82647*10^-7,1.68169*10^-7,1.55302*10^-7,1.43801*10^-7,1.3347*10^-7,1.24145*10^-7,1.15692*10^-7,1.07996*10^-7,1.00963*10^-7,9.45109*10^-8,8.85705*10^-8,8.3081*10^-8,7.7989*10^-8,7.3247*10^-8,6.88117*10^-8,6.46424*10^-8,6.06991*10^-8,5.69398*10^-8,5.33161*10^-8,4.97651*10^-8,4.61922*10^-8,4.24288*10^-8,3.8108*10^-8,3.21756*10^-8,1.96107*10^-8,4.08454*10^-7,5.9923*10^-8,4.60322*10^-8,4.03466*10^-8,3.66988*10^-8,3.38997*10^-8,3.15555*10^-8,2.94963*10^-8,2.76353*10^-8,2.59226*10^-8,2.43268*10^-8,2.28267*10^-8,2.14073*10^-8,2.0057*10^-8,1.87672*10^-8,1.75304*10^-8,1.63409*10^-8,1.51934*10^-8,1.40836*10^-8,1.30076*10^-8,1.19618*10^-8,1.0943*10^-8,9.94819*10^-9,8.97469*10^-9,8.01983*10^-9,7.08112*10^-9,6.15614*10^-9,5.24255*10^-9,4.33803*10^-9,3.44028*10^-9,2.547*10^-9,1.65586*10^-9,7.64482*10^-10,1.29608*10^-10,1.02896*10^-9,1.93628*10^-9,2.85441*10^-9,3.78641*10^-9,4.73557*10^-9,5.70546*10^-9,6.7*10^-9,7.72352*10^-9,8.78084*10^-9,9.87737*10^-9,1.10192*10^-8,1.22133*10^-8,1.34676*10^-8,1.47913*10^-8,1.61951*10^-8,1.76916*10^-8,1.92958*10^-8,2.10255*10^-8,2.29021*10^-8,2.49519*10^-8,2.72072*10^-8,2.97085*10^-8,3.25071*10^-8,3.56686*10^-8,3.92794*10^-8,4.34545*10^-8,4.83514*10^-8,5.41908*10^-8,6.12929*10^-8,7.01401*10^-8,8.14947*10^-8,9.66368*10^-8,1.17894*10^-7,1.49986*10^-7,2.04172*10^-7,3.15551*10^-7,6.77192*10^-7,5.45953*10^-6,5.51271*10^-7,2.92487*10^-7,1.99963*10^-7,1.5238*10^-7,1.23362*10^-7,1.03798*10^-7,8.97001*10^-8,7.90477*10^-8,7.07074*10^-8,6.39937*10^-8,5.84683*10^-8,5.38374*10^-8,4.98967*10^-8,4.65*10^-8,4.35398*10^-8,4.0935*10^-8,3.86237*10^-8,3.65576*10^-8,3.46984*10^-8,3.30156*10^-8,3.14843*10^-8,3.0084*10^-8,2.87981*10^-8,2.76124*10^-8,2.65151*10^-8,2.54962*10^-8,2.45471*10^-8,2.36606*10^-8,2.28302*10^-8,2.20505*10^-8,2.13167*10^-8,2.06245*10^-8,1.99703*10^-8,1.93508*10^-8,1.87631*10^-8,1.82046*10^-8,1.76729*10^-8,1.71661*10^-8,1.66823*10^-8,1.62197*10^-8,1.57768*10^-8,1.53523*10^-8,1.49449*10^-8,1.45535*10^-8,1.41769*10^-8,1.38143*10^-8,1.34647*10^-8,1.31274*10^-8,1.28015*10^-8,1.24865*10^-8,1.21815*10^-8,1.18861*10^-8,1.15996*10^-8,1.13216*10^-8,1.10515*10^-8,1.07889*10^-8,1.05333*10^-8,1.02843*10^-8,1.00415*10^-8,9.80461*10^-9,9.57313*10^-9,9.34676*10^-9,9.12517*10^-9,8.908*10^-9,8.69493*10^-9,8.48564*10^-9,8.27978*10^-9,8.07704*10^-9,7.87707*10^-9,7.67953*10^-9,7.48404*10^-9,7.29022*10^-9}
frf = ListLogPlot[Thread[{xdata, ydata}], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Thick}, PlotLabel -> "Ansys"]
peaks = FindPeaks[frf, 5]
ListLinePlot[frf, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[peaks]}, AspectRatio -> 1/3, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the the first argument to `FindPeaks` in not appropriate.  Change `peaks = FindPeaks[frf, 5]` to `peaks = {#[[1]], ydata[[#[[1]]]]} & /@ FindPeaks[ydata, 5]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it directly, try to find the local maxima in your dataset

```
data = Transpose[{x, Log[y]}];
sol = Cases[Partition[data, 3,1], {{_, a_}, p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}} /; a < b && c< b -> p]
(*{{14, 0.0000193023}, {57, 4.08454*10^-7}, {128, 5.45953*10^-6}}*)

Show[{ListLogPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]], Graphics[{Red, Point[sol]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Execuse me, what is the meaning of `p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}` and what's the meaning of `p:` in it?

Comment: The second argument in `Cases` looks for sublists (Partition, Length 3) of the form `{{_, a_},  {_, b_}, {_, c_}}` . Only the second arguments `a,b,c` are further considered to describe the local peak. `p: `names the middle term of the list, which  is returned via `...->p` if a peak is found.

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich, I get it!